# How to load only the children categories that belong to the current product (magento)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, category

I want to show  a list of categories a product belongs to, top categories and subcategories.

I figured out how to load the correct topcategories, but when I loop the subcats (children categories) it loads ALL subcats of that topcategory, not the categories that the product falls under.

Example:

[image]

Like you can see it loads a ton of subcategories, but only the ones with the red stripe are subcategories that the product falls under.

How can I make sure it only show those under their topcategories?

My code:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
  $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
 //  ->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
 ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
 ->addIsActiveFilter();

  $out = "<ul>";
  foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
      $out .= "<li>";
      $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
      $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
      $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
      // ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cat->getCategoryIds())
      ->load($cat->getId())
      ->getChildrenCategories();
          foreach($children as $child){
              $out .="<li><a href='".$child->getUrl()."'>".$child->getName()."</a></li>";
          }
          $out .="</ul>";
      $out .= "</li>";
  }
  $out .= "</ul>";
  echo $out;
```

[image]

Why are they shown below again? I only want the subcats under the topcategories, not subcats twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your category collection like below-

```
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
      $out .= "<li>";
      $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
      $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
      $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
      // ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cat->getCategoryIds())
      ->load($cat->getId())
      ->getChildrenCategories();
          foreach($children as $child){
              if(in_array($child->getId(), $product->getCategoryIds())){   // change $product->getCategoryIds() to your product category id array
                 $out .="<li><a href='".$child->getUrl()."'>".$child->getName()."</a></li>";
              }
          }
          $out .="</ul>";
      $out .= "</li>";
  }
```

**Update to get parent level categories only** change your category collection to below code

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
 ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
 ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Comment: I get a `Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategoryIds() on null in ` on line 156 which is `if(in_array($child->getId(), $product->getCategoryIds())){   // change $product->getCategoryIds() to your product category id array`

Comment: please change `$product->getCategoryIds()` to variable of  array of product category ids, may be with $currentCatIds

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work (kinda) but now my subcats are loaded not only under the topcats, but they are shown as if they are topcats. I will add an image as an example

Comment: I added the image

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! It works. Is there a way to change in what order the categories are shown?

Comment: tell me in which order you want to show categories?

Comment: I want food first, then allergenen, is there a way I can lookup their ids, and set the order how they are loaded?

Comment: you can sort them by id and name, but I am not sure you can sort  them by a specific order